# Does $f$ being continuous, differentiable imply $f'$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$, continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$. Does this imply $f'$ is continuous on $(a,b)$? I feel like this is true intuitively

Comment: This is one of those classic questions that every good calculus student seems to have at some point in their lives <3

Comment: lol i guess i'm a "good calculus student". hooray

Comment: If this question occurs to you while you're starting off studying calculus, I'd bet on you having a decent mind for learning math in the long run :)

Comment: well I'm trying my best lol. I will say that as a stat major I have to take real analysis 1,2 and it has given me a whole new level of respect for math majors

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, no. However $f'$ is severely constrained in this instance. It can be shown that $f'$ actually satisfies the conclusion of the intermediate value theorem. To give an example of this phenomenon, take $f(x) = x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ when $x\ne 0$, and $f(0) = 0$. Then $f$ is differentiable everywhere, but its derivative is not continuous at the origin.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)